# Remove \n from XML attributes

Tags: java, xml

```
<Task>Reading</Task>
<day/>
<month/>
<year/>
```

Here I want to display this as same, but for coding a java class I need to remove `\n` between the elements, while parsing. Because I have to remove empty elements.
Can anyone help me how to parse and remove \n in XML?

The element `<day/>` is empty here. while parsing I should not get this `<day>`.
Need to check a condition, if an element has a value, it should display. Otherwise, it should not display.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you show the output you want?

Comment: I don't see there any empty attributes. You probably talking about elements :)

Comment: Please elaborate and make your question more clear.

Comment: I don't see any attributes at all, only elements. What's the question here?

Comment: I also don't see any connection between removing \n and removing empty elements, yet you say you have to do the former 'because' you have to do the latter. Not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing people by talking about attributes when you mean elements.

I don't see the connection between stripping/ignoring the whitespace between elements, and detecting when the content of an element is empty. Both tasks are very easy; you need to be clearer why you are having difficulty. Showing the code you have written always helps us to understand where you are going wrong.